# How to correct a specific JavaScript/TypeScript type in an IDE at compiler time?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Imagine we have a line of code like:

```js
class Test{
    /** @type {(e : Event)=> void} */ test;
}

var test2 = new Test();
test2.test = (e) => {}
```

If you use that code in e.g. VS Code, you would notice that the `e` in the last line will have type `any`.

I want to fix that behaviour. I want to create a plugin, an extension, for TypeScript, for VS Code, or anything else. I already read all kinds of documentations about language services, language servers, VS Code extensions and TypeScript extensions.

---

My goal: i simply want to turn on "noImplicitAny" and if possible even "noExplicitAny" on my whole solution. but sadly i can't do that because as of now every HTML event arg i manually specify as an expression body gets type any. so i would need to add dozens, if not hundreds of lines of code to explicitly cast each of those event args to a type that can easily be inferred.

nobody bothered to bundle that functionality in an already existing plugin. at least as per my knowledge

Comment: What are trying to do? Are you trying to get the type hint in the comments of a `.js` file to work when imported into a `.ts` file? Because [that seems to work.](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-bas-9wh4ke?file=/src/index.ts) Please clarify what you're goal is and link to an example if you can.

Comment: updated... i don't want to make it work, i want to make it 100% type safe. i can't count how many bugs we had just because events are inferred as any types. spelling mistakes, object type mismatches, rename functions not being called.

Comment: The JSDoc type is not as "strong" as the equivalent TypeScript type would be. If you change that to `test: (e: Event) => void;` then the assigned function gets a correct type for `e`, but the class definition is no longer valid (because you don't assign `test`). Could you add an example of some _actual_ code, not a `Test.test` thing?

Comment: well then i need to improve JSDoc, because we're using a vanilla javascript framework that uses JSDoc to get close to typesciprts type safety. don't judge, it can't be changed, there were various reasons against using typescript, so i, as a clean coder, need to somehow make javascript as type-scripty as possible without people getting annoyed. which is why i need to write a language plugin, which then leads back to this question ;)

Comment: So this has really nothing to do with actual TypeScript...

Comment: well it basically is, type inferring is a feature of typescript that's used in many javascript projects.

Comment: Your IDE or editor may (or may not) do type inference and type hints based on JSDoc comments or TypeScript annotations, but since you're not actually writing TypeScript (and evidently can't use TypeScript syntax), I wouldn't say this has much to do with TypeScript itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing an extension you could just add a type declaration file (aka. typings) to your node modules.

A type declaration is a special typescript file with ambient types, that is, declarations of types, variables etc. without actually implementing any of that. These declarations are used for code hints and type checks, when using a JS library. Node modules generated from projects that use Typescript for development automatically generate also the type declaration file(s) (*.d.ts), so this is a pretty common approach.

For many JS libraries there are already type descriptions (see [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)), maybe for your's too? If not you can create such a type declaration manually. Just read up in the TS handbook and follow the references from the link above to learn how.

Comment: in my case that's sadly not possible. also i do not want the developer (me/us) to take any action. the type is already defined, so i want to implmenet a solution, where the developer doesn't need to do anything. i want to implement a logic like "if typeof right-hand-side is any -> typeof right-hand-side = typeof left-hand-side"

Comment: also adding a d.ts file is even worse than specifying the cast manually...